# [SOLVED] Error 127 when importing project into Eclipse

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm having trouble importing my package into Eclipse. It worked before, but since a few days it causes trouble. When I open resp. try to import my project the following error message is displayed:

```
Description                                     Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error 127 occurred while running autoreconf     follow_me           -1          Configure Problem
```

I removed my previous version of Eclipse and installed the newest version: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). Previously I used Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0).

According to [this tutorial on the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/IDEs?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22IDEs%22#Creating_the_Eclipse_project_files) I performed the following steps to import the project:

1. In folder catkin_ws: `catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`
2. `awk -f $(rospack find mk)/eclipse.awk build/.project > build/.project_with_env && mv build/.project_with_env build/.project`
3. Started Eclipse in a new terminal by: `bash -i -c ~/Software/Eclipse/eclipse/eclipse` (Note: I sourced ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash in ~/.bashrc )
4. In Eclipse: *File > Import... > General > Existing Projects into Workspace > Next > As root directory: /home/username/catkin_ws/src/follow_me > No other option selected > Finish*

The Console output tells:

```
CDT Build Console [follow_me]
Build stopped
()
```

And the aforementioned error is shown under the "Problems" tab.
Also the "src" folder is grayed out as well as the containing source files.

I've already tried to reimport my package. Also I can't finish step 4 when I create a new empty package in catkin_ws.

I'm using **ROS Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) with kernel version 4.15.0-47-generic**.

What can I do to properly import and use my package in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:
(See my answer below.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320867/%5Bsolved%5D-error-127-when-importing-project-into-eclipse/) by [Zacryon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40560/zacryon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-16**:
Please post your `UPDATE` as an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Zacryon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40560/zacryon/) on 2019-04-16**:
Done. Except accepting my own answer, since I do not have 10 points yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to solve this myself. I'm not sure why this error occurred nor what exactly solved the problem. But here is what I've tried: Instead of importing the project as existing project, I chose to import from makefile and chose the CMakeLists.txt from my projects source folder. There I had to setup some paths for correct inclusion of the headers and the problem was gone. But since I thought that this was a rather ugly solution I deleted the project from the workspace and reimported it again, but this time as existing project (like in the tutorial). After that (and setting up some paths again) the problem was magically gone. I still don't know why though.

---

Originally posted by [Zacryon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40560/zacryon/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0